# Getting Exception androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.view.TextureView

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to kotlin in android. 
I followed this "https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#9" tutorial but got following error. 
the app is built successfully however, app stops and the message on my phone says "app keeps stopping".

I also followed the tutorial in here https://developer.android.com/training/camera
but no luck, it starts but do not capture any image. All i wanna do is to get frame from realtime video stream and work on frames. Any help.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 28612
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.view.TextureView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.view.TextureView
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

My xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/capture_button"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my main is

```
// This is an arbitrary number we are using to keep track of the permission
// request. Where an app has multiple context for requesting permission,
// this can help differentiate the different contexts.
private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
// This is an array of all the permission specified in the manifest.
private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // Add this at the end of onCreate function
        viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.view_finder)
        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            viewFinder.post { startCamera() }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }
        // Every time the provided texture view changes, recompute layout
        viewFinder.addOnLayoutChangeListener { _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _ ->
            updateTransform()
        }
    }
    // Add this after onCreate
    private val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    private lateinit var viewFinder: TextureView
    private fun startCamera() {
       ...
        }
        .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextureView //changed from textView to TextureView

        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/capture_button"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `view_finder` view in the layout of `MainActivity` is `AppCompatTextView` and you are trying to assign it into a `TextureView` here:

```
viewFinder = findViewById(R.id.view_finder)
```

Change one of them to match the other.